# Deploy an app on a remote server with git

Tags: git, web-applications, cloud

Is it a good practice to deploy a web app on a cloud server using git ? that means cloning the repo from github or bitbucket and then running it. Are there better ways to do so ? e.g:launching an FTP Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a potential security risk to use a Git workspace as the website directory. Because a  Git workspace (the "work tree") contains the `.git` directory, and if you make a configuration mistake, or the website gets hacked, the `.git` directory might get exposed or leaked.

A safer way is to separate the Git repository and the working tree, for example like this:

```
git clone your_remote_repo_url /path/to/repo
mkdir /path/to/deployment
cd /path/to/repo
git checkout --work-tree /path/to/deployment -f
```

In this setup, `/path/to/deployment` is a regular directory, without a `.git` folder. The risk of the `.git` folder ever getting exposed is smaller this way. You can still perform Git operations on the deployment directory using the `--work-tree` flag as in the `checkout` example above.

I do this way only on production sites, on DEV sites I use regular clones.